# Template type argument `T` where `T*` expands to `nullptr_t`

Tags: c++, templates, nullptr

What I'm looking for is basically this:

```
template <typename T> 
struct a { 
    using pointer_type = T*;
};
```

What I want is such `X` so that `a<X>::pointer_type` evaluates to `nullptr_t`. Is this possible?

Edit: This is what I actually need (the `pointer_type` is hidden in the signatures of the `ENCODER` and `DECODER` template arguments as `MSG *`)

```
template <int MSGNUM,
    typename MSG,
    int(&ENCODER)(const MsgHeader* pHeader, const MSG* pMessage, unsigned char* destBuf, int destBufSize),
    int(&DECODER)(const MsgHeader* pHeader, const unsigned char* msgBody, int msgBodyLen, MSG* decodedMsg)>
struct msgid {
    using msg_type = MSG;
    static constexpr int msgnum = MSGNUM;
    static constexpr auto encoder = ENCODER;
    static constexpr auto decoder = DECODER;
};

using MSG1 = msgid<1,msg1struct,encodeMsg1,decodeMsg1>;
using MSG2 = msgid<2,msg2struct,encodeMsg2,decodeMsg2>;
using HDRONLY= msgid<-1,X,encodeHdr,decodeHdr>;
```

HDRONLY would have to accept a nullptr where the decoded msg structure is used.

Comment: `nullptr_t` is not a pointer type. (And `nullptr` is not a pointer, despite what certain current compiler error messages say.) This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why would you want this? What would `T` be in your scenario?

Comment: To me, this looks like two different templates.

Comment: @molbdnilo Look again: the pointer_type is hidden in the signatures of the ENCODER and DECODER template arguments, specifically the MSG* parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) from the `<type_traits>` header:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

// ...

template <typename T> 
struct a { 
    using pointer_type = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, std::nullptr_t>::value,
                             std::nullptr_t,
                             T*
                         >::type;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, @Ruks! I have added an answer based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

`std::nullptr_t` is not a pointer type. It's a type with an implicit conversion to any pointer type.

You could have a specialisation:

```
template <> struct a<std::nullptr_t> { using pointer_type = std::nullptr_t; };
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ruks this is what I came up with:

```
template <int MSGNUM,
    typename MSG,
    int(&ENCODER)(const MsgHeader* pHeader, typename std::conditional<std::is_same<MSG, std::nullptr_t>::value, std::nullptr_t, const MSG *>::type pMessage, unsigned char* destBuf, int destBufSize),
    int(&DECODER)(const MsgHeader* pHeader, const unsigned char* msgBody, int msgBodyLen, typename std::conditional<std::is_same<MSG, std::nullptr_t>::value, std::nullptr_t, MSG *>::type decodedMsg)>
struct msgid {
    using msg_type = MSG;
    static constexpr int msgnum = MSGNUM;
    static constexpr auto encoder = ENCODER;
    static constexpr auto decoder = DECODER;
};
```